# Looking for custom EV3 block to control LEDs independently

Tags: ev3, ev3-g

The EV3 brick has 2 LED sets, one on the left side of the button panel and one on the right.

Software such as [python for ev3dev](https://pypi.org/project/python-ev3dev2/) let's you control them both individually, the normal EV3-G LED block however only allows to set them both to the same value.

Has anybody created a custom block that I can import into EV3-G that allows me to control the left and right LEDs individually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to control the LEDs separately using the official EV3 firmware. You would have to modify the kernel drivers. You can only use the predefined patterns shown [here](https://github.com/mindboards/ev3sources/blob/78ebaf5b6f8fe31cc17aa5dce0f8e4916a4fc072/lms2012/d_ui/Linuxmod_AM1808/d_ui.c#L323-L330).

```
ULONG     LEDPATTERNDATA[NO_OF_LEDS + 1][LEDPATTERNS] =
{ //  LED_BLACK   LED_GREEN   LED_RED    LED_ORANGE           LED_GREEN_FLASH                     LED_RED_FLASH                     LED_ORANGE_FLASH                      LED_GREEN_PULSE                       LED_RED_PULSE                      LED_ORANGE_PULSE
  {  0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0b00000000000000000000000000000000, 0b00000000000000000111110000011111, 0b00000000000000000111110000011111, 0b00000000000000000000000000000000, 0b00000000000000000000000001110111, 0b00000000000000000000000001110111 }, // RR
  {  0x00000000, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0x00000000, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0b00000000000000000111110000011111, 0b00000000000000000000000000000000, 0b00000000000000000111110000011111, 0b00000000000000000000000001110111, 0b00000000000000000000000000000000, 0b00000000000000000000000001110111 }, // RG
  {  0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0b00000000000000000000000000000000, 0b00000000000000000111110000011111, 0b00000000000000000111110000011111, 0b00000000000000000000000000000000, 0b00000000000000000000000001110111, 0b00000000000000000000000001110111 }, // LR
  {  0x00000000, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0x00000000, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0b00000000000000000111110000011111, 0b00000000000000000000000000000000, 0b00000000000000000111110000011111, 0b00000000000000000000000001110111, 0b00000000000000000000000000000000, 0b00000000000000000000000001110111 }, // LG
  { 0 }
};
```